# Javascript getlocation permission issue on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am using the code below to ask for location permission only for iOS devices when the component renders, below is the code snippet:

```
if (!!navigator.platform && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      success => {
        if (success) {
          const coords = {
            lat: success.coords.latitude,
            lng: success.coords.longitude,
          };
          this.fetchNearestLocation(coords);
          this.setState({ showCurrLocationMarker: true });
          this.setState({ isCurrentLocationBlocked: false });
        }
      },
      error => {
        if (error && error.code) {
          this.setState({ showCurrLocationMarker: false });
          this.setState({ isCurrentLocationBlocked: true });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The issue here is that once the location access is blocked for Safari browser from the settings, and after sometime it is enabled again, I won't get the location permission popup at all on other websites as well.

I am confused whether the issue is related to the code or the browser (settings).

I was expecting to get a location permission pop-up on when the component renders on an iOS device on Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to limitations in the security mechanism of iOS devices, which cannot force location permission pop-up windows through JavaScript code. Therefore, if your code cannot pop up a location permission pop-up, it may be due to the user prohibiting location access, rather than a code issue.

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    console.log('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude);
    console.log('Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude);
  }, function(error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  });
} else {
  console.error('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
}
```